# How do I fetch a value from a var file using Jinja2 into an JSON file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I would like to fetch/replace a value in the input YAML — *abc.yml* — from a var file — *var.yml* — based on the matching `id` value (here `id` value is `123`) between input file and var file using Jinja2 and create a JSON as expected result.

Jinja2 code:

```
[
    {% for list in abc['fwrules'] %}
        {
            {% for item in abc['details'] %}
            "country": "{{item.Country}}",
            "destCidr": "{{list.destCidr}}"
            {% endfor %}
        }{% if not loop.last %},
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Input yml — *abc.yml*:

```yaml
---
details: 
         -   Country: "abc" 
             id: 123 
fwrules:
         -   destCidr: "{{ DNS }}, 10.20.20.20/24"
             srcCidr: "10.30.20.20/24"

         -   destCidr: "10.30.30.30/24"
             srcCidr: "{{ NTP }}, 10.40.20.20/24"
```

Var file — *var.yml*:

```yaml
---
names:
    -   id: "123"
        DNS: "10.10.10.10"
        NTP: "10.100.100.100"

    -   id: "456"
        DNS: "20.20.20.20"
        NTP: "10.200.200.200"
```

Expected JSON result:

```json
[
    {
        "country": "abc",
        "destCidr": "10.10.10.10, 10.20.20.20/24",
        "srcCidr": "10.30.20.20/24"
    },
    {
        "country": "abc",
        "destCidr": "10.30.30.30/24"
        "srcCidr": "10.100.100.100, 10.40.20.20/24"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the usage of filters only.

Given the two yaml — *abc.yml* and *var.yml* — you provided, using this two tasks:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}.yml"
  loop:
    - var
    - abc

- set_fact:
    output: >-
      {{
        output | default([]) 
          + [{
            'country': details.0.Country,
            'destCidr': item.destCidr,
            'srcCidr': item.srcCidr
          }] 
      }} 
  loop: "{{ fwrules }}"
  vars: 
    _matched_id: >-
      {{ 
        names 
        | selectattr('id', 'eq', details.0.id | string) 
        | first 
      }}
    DNS: "{{ _matched_id.DNS }}"
    NTP: "{{ _matched_id.NTP }}"
```

Would create a variable `output` having your desired output.

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": [
        {
            "country": "abc",
            "destCidr": "10.10.10.10, 10.20.20.20/24",
            "srcCidr": "10.30.20.20/24"
        },
        {
            "country": "abc",
            "destCidr": "10.30.30.30/24",
            "srcCidr": "10.100.100.100, 10.40.20.20/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can, then, dump that output in a JSON file if that's what you need:

```yaml
- copy:
    content: "{{ output | to_nice_json }}"
    dest: output.json
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution and that really helps. I have actually reduced the total JOSN in the abc.yml. Suppose if i have many attributes in a list in the input file-abc.yml and not only destCidr and i have more than 1 value to be looked up in the var.yml file. I am updating the above abc.yml, var.yml. Appreciate your help

Comment: The idea is nearly the same. See updated answer @Vinny.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. That really helps